# React Native - React hook: Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

When I click several times of `+1 button`, wait a while and click several times again, then an error msg will appear :

> "index.js:1 Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function.
> in Image (at Test.js:31)
> in Imagecomponent (at Test.js:41)"

But if I remove the `Imagecomponent`, the error will be disappear, would like to keep on the structure of this program and if possible try to make the Image not flickering

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { TouchableHighlight, Text, Image } from 'react-native';

export default function Test() {
    const imagePath = require('./assets/image.png')
    const [count, setCount] = useState(0)
    const [msg, setMsg] = useState("")
    useEffect(()=>{
        changeMsg()
    },[count])

    const changeMsg=()=>{
        let temp = 0
        for(let i = 0; i < 1000000000; i++){
            temp += 1
        }
        let newMsg = "newMsg = " + count
        setMsg(newMsg)
    }
    const Imagecomponent=()=>{
        return(
            <>
            <Image style={{height: 40, width: 40}} source={imagePath}></Image>
            <Image style={{height: 40, width: 40}} source={imagePath}></Image>
            <Image style={{height: 40, width: 40}} source={imagePath}></Image>
            <Image style={{height: 40, width: 40}} source={imagePath}></Image>
            <Image style={{height: 40, width: 40}} source={imagePath}></Image>
            <Image style={{height: 40, width: 40}} source={imagePath}></Image>
            </>
        )
    }

    return(
        <>
        <TouchableHighlight onPress={()=>{setCount(count+1)}}><Text>+1</Text></TouchableHighlight>
        <Text>{msg}</Text>
        <Imagecomponent/>
        </>
    )
}
```

Comment: What is the purpose of for loop inside changeMsg function?

Comment: @J.Doe Just to create a function that takes some times to run, this is just a simple version of my other program, the original function do take some time for some calculation task

Comment: @GGprogram if you want to create a delay is better that you use window.setTimeout, otherwise you are blocking the main thread

Comment: What do you cant to achive? Do you want to display the number of clicks? Because you can do it much easier, you don't really need to use the useEffect at all.

Comment: @Manjar what I want to do will be: onClick=>setCount+1 and call a calculation function, and the calculation function will use count as input, so i just put the calculation function in useEffect so everytime I call the function will using the latest count value

Comment: But I'm afraid you are killing performance if you do a 'long task' on every render, I can see its use in a real aplicación. If you need to do such a large calcularon I belive you must realy on backend side for them

Comment: @Manjar The reason I use useEffect is because i would like to use the updated state, will it be better if I just pass the value as function parm so that I need not to use useEffect?

Comment: Yes, take in mind that on next render the state will be updated, so you can just use the variable count as updated to its latest value

Answer (score 0):

You are doing a wrong use of useEffect. This hook is meant for asynchronus operations like for example doing an Ajax request. But here you are using it synchronously, and the only operation you do is to update the state of the message. So on every click you render twice, once for the count update, on the other for the update of the message.

The error is cause because you block the main thread so much time that react triggers a timeout.

If you want to just display the number of clicks this is much easier:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { TouchableHighlight, Text, Image } from 'react-native';

const Imagecomponent=()=>{
    return(
        <>
            <Image style={{height: 40, width: 40}} source={imagePath}></Image>
            <Image style={{height: 40, width: 40}} source={imagePath}></Image>
            <Image style={{height: 40, width: 40}} source={imagePath}></Image>
            <Image style={{height: 40, width: 40}} source={imagePath}></Image>
            <Image style={{height: 40, width: 40}} source={imagePath}></Image>
            <Image style={{height: 40, width: 40}} source={imagePath}></Image>
        </>
    )
}

export default function Test() {
    const imagePath = require('./assets/image.png')
    const [count, setCount] = useState(0)

    let message = `newMsg ${count}`

    return(
        <>
            <TouchableHighlight onPress={()=>{setCount(count+1)}}><Text>+1</Text></TouchableHighlight>
            <Text>{message}</Text>
            <Imagecomponent/>
        </>
    )
}
```

I moved the ImageComponent out of the render function, because you are "redeclaring" this component on every render, you should never declare a Component inside the render function.